# Ionic 3 Web application + Google Analytics

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, web-applications, google-analytics

I've developed Ionic 3 (Angular 4) application for 3 platforms: 
 - iOS
 - Android
 - web application

I faced an issue when I tried to use the google analytics plugin for the web application. As it's deployed as a web application I don't have cordova available, so I cannot use any cordova plugins (like I normally did for iOS/android). Does anyone have experience with it and can share some thoughts, ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the cordova browser platform to use cordova plugins for your web application. The [google analytics plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) (I assume you used this one) supports the browser platform so it should work just fine.

To add the browser platform run the following command:

```
cordova platform add browser
```

And to run it:

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

Comment: It was helpful for me to do `ionic cordova build browser` and then run `http-server`. Of course before that install `npm install http-server -g`